# React & Redux: How do I fire events in parents before firing events in children?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've been trying to fire events (i.e. call a Redux action) in the root component before child components do so.

[image]

In this diagram...

- The parent (i.e. Owner) has an action `fetchData()`. When the URL is `/`, we'll see this `parent` only.
- The child  (i.e. Ownee) has an action `getDetail(id)`. When the URL is `/child`, we'll see this `child` upon the `parent`.
- Both components fire events in `componentWillMount`

The problem is, when you visit the `/child` directly, `fetchData()` is called **after `getDetail(id)` is called.**

(When you visit `/` and visit `/chile`, `fetchData()` is fired first.)

Is it possible to fire events from the higher components to lower components?

**P.S.**

Here is a context of this problem...

The parent is a list of blog posts, and its children are detail pages, where you'll see the detail of an individual blog post.

On the list (parent page), you'll click a `detail` button, which will lead you to the detail page. To achieve this, it is necessary to get all the items before showing the detail of them.

Comment: It might help to explain why it matters to you -- what is the problem?

Comment: @ Cymen Thanks. I updated this post.

Comment: fyi completely changed my answer after you provided context.

Answer (score 2):

Edit - updated to reflect your response above.

I think the right approach is to let your state reflect the possible ways to reach the detail page.  Let `fetchData()` actually determine whether fetching is necessary, and call it from both the parent and the child component.

It sounds like you are using react-router or a similar approach - this situation is very common.  I would suggest you keep track of the current selected id (which is undefined if you're viewing the list of posts), then render the child item when it is available.

I don't think the order of lifecycle methods is the real problem assuming that fetchData() is asynchronous.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Yes, I'm using `react-router`. I thought that it would be the most efficient way to get all the `posts` in the parent and get a single `post` from the parent (`PostList`) to a child (`Post`) when necessary.

I'm not really sure if keeping track of the selected ID works, since you may directly go to an URL with a particular ID (or refresh the browser), which will inevitably loses the list of posts.

Answer (score 1):

So the way to approach this is to think about what your components are doing. You should have a home page that lists the posts by title and date or whatever it is you decide. Then when you click on one, it goes to the page with the blog post.

So you should have a `PostList` component and a `Post` component. `PostList` should fetch all of the data needed to display the list. `Post` should fetch all of the data to show the post. When you render `PostList`, it should not be rendering any `Post`. `Post` should only render when you're on a URL for a post. To get that behavior, you need a router like [found](https://github.com/4Catalyzer/found) or [react router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router).

Now it might turn out that `PostList` is getting all of the details that `Post` needs to display each blog post. That is fine. Your state management should detect you already have the blog post and not fetch it. That is why you see actions like `fetchBlogPostIfNeeded` -- invoking that function typically checks the local state to see if the blog post is already present, if so, it does nothing. If not, it actually fetches it.

With this combination and the appropriate server-side routing, your blog should support a hard refresh on either the list of posts or when you are viewing an individual post. The key part though is that you are using the URL to go from the list to the post. To do that, you would use the `Link` component (both found and react router have a component with the same name that does this).

Comment: And later on, you'll debate and think about whether these components should fetch their own data. I only mention it before someone else mentions it -- it's definitely something to think about but start with the basics and build upon it with better practices as you learn them.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Maybe the last sentence of your comment, "start with the basics and build upon it with better practices as you learn them", would be the most appropriate solution for me. Letting each `Post` fetch a single post seems simpler than getting a post from the existing list of posts (even though it's not the most memory-efficient way).